# Run an update query at a regular interval

Tags: sql-server

My requirement is to run an update query which will update a table from another table, 
this part is ok. 
I want the query to run in a regular time interval. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Agent, which is a separate component of SQL Server to perform routine and scheduled tasks. You haven't provided much detail about the query you want to execute, but you should be able to find what you need in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Another alternative is to use Windows' Scheduled Tasks and have it run `osql.exe` on a regular basis, using the command-line arguments to specify the query text or the filename of a *.sql script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a SQL Server Agent Job
2. On the 'General' page: Give the job a name, e.g. 'MyCleanupJob'
3. On the 'Steps' page:

   3.1 Give a step a name, e.g 'Step1 - Update records'

   3.2 Select desired database

   3.3 In the 'Command' box, put your T-SQL update statement(s) here
4. Finally create a schedule

   In the screenshot below, I've created a schedule which will execute the agent job ever hour starting at 9:00am to 10:00pm (inclusive).

[image]